# DDEMLException: 0x400a A client's attempt to establish a conversation has failed

Tags: java, dde, dynamic-data-exchange

When I try to run the example of pretty-tools-JDDE-2.0.3-examples+jdde-binaries

```
pretty-tools-JDDE-2.0.3-examples+jdde-binaries>java -cp .;pretty-tools-JDDE-2.0.3.jar ExcelAdviceExample
```

I got this error

```
Connecting...
DDEMLException: 0x400a A client's attempt to establish a conversation has failed.
```

Im using windows 10, my java is

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't start a DDE server. If you are following the examples you should start the example server: http://jdde.pretty-tools.com/en/examples/ddeserverexample.htm

Answer (score 0):

For some DDE servers, it is required that you run your program/IDE as administrator